# How to use JSON to store the data from input field

Tags: json

i have request and response json arrays for create new customer you can see it at the following link:
http://api.shopify.com/customer.html#create

I have a html form in my page for customer registration. Can you please tell me how can i call the json in my page to store the data entered in the input fields on my page. Please advise.

Following is the HTMl form whose values i want to store in json array:

Store Name *

 Contact Name *
Shipping Address
 Address 1 *

 Address 2

 City *

 State / Province *

 Zip Code / Postal Code *

 Country *

 Phone Number *

 Email Address *

 Join Mailing List?

 How did you hear about us? Comments?

Answer (score 0):

Create a form to input data

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<label>Text:</label>
<input type="text" name="text" id="date" value=""  />
<label>Paragraph:</label>
<textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="save to json" />    
</form>
```

Save your data in a `.json` file

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["text"])) {
  $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/data.json';
  file_put_contents($file, json_encode($_REQUEST));
}
?>
```

the `data.json` file you saved will look like this

```
{"text":"testdemo","textarea":"parademo"}
```

hope this helps